# Plot 3 column of data set in one Plot

Tags: plotting

How can i Plot  3 column of data set in one Log Plot?. Is there any one who can answer me? See thereare 3 labelled axis

regards
Atif[image]

Comment: I am not sure what you want. If you plot with option  `Frame`-> True you can add labels using option  `FrameLabel`. Does that help?

Comment: Look at the top of plot you see the labeling of number. it mean somebody plot it with datapoints of row in dataset. 3 column points are plotted against each other

Comment: labelling is not my issue. i think there is some command to plot 3 data point of dataset aginst each other as depicted in Fig

Comment: Table[{M16yc1[[jj, 15]]*10^7, M16yc1[[jj, 7]]}, {jj, 1, Length[M16yc1]}];.two datapoints are plotting to each other. x,y axis.

Comment: How can i include dataset in it to plot 3rd point against two of them

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave us a simple example. You could add this to your question. To plot several plots together you can use `Show`.

Comment: Look at the values pf top of plot 10^12, 10^14, 10^16. How it comes on Plot

Comment: If you look at the option `Ticks`  is that what you want? Or `FrameTicks`.An example of the plots you are trying to combine would be helpful.

Comment: Hugh. Not working

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. Then we can have a go ourselves. Please paste it into your original question in a way that we can copy it into a Mathematica notebook and try and get you a solution. It is impossible to guess what you are trying to do.

Comment: Give us some sample data and some sense of what you want to do. I have _literally_ no idea what that plot is supposed to be showing (personally I think it's a garbage plot and the researchers got lazy in their data presentation). We'd need sample data and some sense of what features of that plot you want to reproduce before we can begin to have a go at it.