# 3-axis plot from a dataset

Tags: plotting

[image]
How can I plot 3 axis on one plot. There are 3 data set points which are plotted against each other

Comment: This is the same question that you asked [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/219379/12558). We can only help if you give us some code to work with. Please show us what you have tried. Please invent a simple example for us to work with.

Comment: Also, have you seen [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/627/1-plot-2-scale-axis?rq=1) question? They're using 2 different vertical axes, but it shouldn't be a problem to switch it to the horizontal axes.

Comment: Mass defect so plz tell me the solution